# How to handle multiple PouchDB instances in the browser that sync with the same db?

Tags: pouchdb

What is the recommended way of dealing with multiple PouchDB instances in the browser that synchronize simultaneously with the same remote/local database?

My setup is a web application in the browser that synchronizes continuously with a remote CouchDB.
That web app could be opened more than once (multiple tabs/windows) and thus create multiple PouchDB instances that try to sync.

In such a case, only one PouchDB instance will report remote changes - other instances produce a conflict during live sync:

```
{
  error: true,
  message: "Document update conflict",
  name: "conflict",
  result: {
    doc_write_failures: 0,
    docs_read: 1,
    docs_written: 1,
    end_time: ...,
    errors: [
      CustomPouchError
    ],
    last_seq: 963,
    ok: false,
    start_time: ...,
    status: "aborting"
  },
  status: 409
}
```

Do I need to ensure that only one PouchDB instance syncs at a time and pass changes around manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PouchDB replication currently does not work in multiple tabs. It is [an open issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2493), and anybody who wants to hop in would be more than welcome to. :)

Comment: Thanks! Should have checked issues first... For some reason I wasn't using changes on the local database, so that already helps a lot.

Comment: Hi @nlawson, any update on this? I saw that the issue you mention was closed, and a new one is referenced: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1852 

Should this issue fix the problem with several Pouchdb instances on different tabs?

Comment: I believe the current status is that https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1852 is still unresolved, meaning that replication in multiple tabs will work, but it'll just be inefficient.